# Mobile app and RESTful API in Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication, jwt

I'm using JWT to authenticate users on my Laravel back-end form the mobile app. How can I keep them authenticated until they log out? The users get logged out once the app is closed. Is it possible to prevent this, like Facebook app does for example?

Comment: Have you set the proper authentication guard for your application in `config\auth.php`, the `api` is used for token based guard.

Comment: Are you saving the token? What does happen to the token when you close the app?

Comment: @Bravi same question here! how did you solve that! i want to authenticate users just one time

Comment: @AliSherafat, if you're using Lumen, then it has a built-in token based authentication. Basically, you save the token in the localStorage for mobile apps and then on the app you can do a check - if the token exists in local storage, then proceed. Otherwise, restrict the user from accessing other tabs on the app. What is your current setup?

Comment: @Bravi i'm using Laravel 5.2 and i want to authenticate users in angular js and android app. i implemented jwt and it's ok for angular but not android! the tokens life time is only one hour so my android users should login again and again :( finally i decided to use api key packages like api-guard